# Replace ListView Item each press a Button

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create a listview which can accommodate different types of data, each data type is displayed when I press a button of some kind of button that I provide. How to change the data displayed when I press a different button?? Anyone who knows,please tell me how to do it...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at "Shared Preference", where you can have list of different type of datas and letting user to pick one.

Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

You can have Shared Preference in the setting. It will look better than having button to change the data.

Hope it helps